# How can I prove that a list of polynomials is linearly dependent?

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

A book I am reading has the following problem:

> Suppose $p_0, p_1, \ldots, p_m$ are polynomials in
> $\mathcal{P}_m(\mathbb{F})$ such that $p_j(2) = 0$ for each $j$. Prove
> that $p_0, p_1, \ldots, p_m$ is not linearly independent in
> $\mathcal{P}_m(\mathbb{F})$.

I have attempted the following solution:

Suppose $p_0, p_1, \ldots, p_m$ are linearly independent. Then:

$$
0 = a_0 p_0 + \ldots + a_m p_m
$$

where $a_0 = \ldots = a_m = 0$ is the only solution. However:

$$
0 = b_0 p_0(2) + \ldots + b_m p_m(2)
$$

where $b_0, \ldots, b_m \in \mathbb{F}$.

Hence there is a contradiction, and $p_0, p_1, \ldots, p_m$ are not linearly independent.

However, I am not convinced this is correct. I am worried I have conflated the real value $0$, given by $p_j(2) = 0$ and $0$ representing the $0$ polynomial (the additive identify for polynomials). Then again, I wonder if these two $0$ values are equivalent and hence my proof is correct.

So my questions: 1) is the proof correct 2) if not, how do I show that $0$ can be made from a linear combination of $p_0, p_1, \ldots, p_m$, such that the coefficients are not all $0$.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint** Let $F : \mathcal{P}_m(\mathbb{F}) \to \mathbb{F}$ defined by
$$F(P)=P(2)$$

Then this is an onto homomorphism of $\mathbb{F}$-vector spaces. Deduce from here that
$$\dim(\ker(F)) = \dim( \mathcal{P}_m(\mathbb{F}) ) -1= m$$

All your polynomials are in $\ker(F)$.

Answer (score 2):

Your proof is wrong. Hint: $P_m$ has dimension $m+1$. If you intersect it with $\{f | f(2)=0\}$ you get a proper subspace of dimension at most $m$. Finally. in a $\le m$-dim space any $m+1$ elements are linearly  dependent.

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is wrong because $\sum b_ip_i(x)=0$ at one point $x$  (with not all $b_i$'s equal to $0$) does not imply that  $p_i$'s are linearly dependent.

Our polynomials all belong to span of  $\{x-2,(x-2)^{2},..,(x-2)^{m}\}$ since they vanish at $x=2$. If they were independent then a space of dimension $m$ would have  $m+1$ linearly independent elements which is  contradiction.

Comment: $x-2$ does not belong to that span. I think you mean the span of $\{ (x-2), (x-2)^2,...,...\}$

Comment: @N.S. Thank you. I wrongly read $p_i(2)=0$ as $p_i(0)=0$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. How would I show that $0$ has more than one representation as a linear combination of $p_0, \ldots, p_m$? Dimensions are in the next chapter of my book, so I am fairly sure this is the method in which the book 'expects' this to be solved.